# File Formats Supported by UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am using `UIwebview` to display documents on iPad coming from SAP in various formats like .doc , .xls , .pdf etc etc 
We are facing an issue while displaying .msg / .elm ( mail files ) as attachments on webview .
we have .msg file uplaoded as an attachment in SAP like other docs .
Exact error we are getting is something like this

```
2012-08-09 12:19:56.311 Appname[62035:15203] Error loading attachment 
 Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x13041dc0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/Admin/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/190DB7F1-F0EF-4333-A802-B07A71B989BC/Documents/State%20of%20the%20Viacom%20Business.msg, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/Admin/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/190DB7F1-F0EF-4333-A802-B07A71B989BC/Documents/State%20of%20the%20Viacom%20Business.msg, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}
2012-08-09 12:19:56.312 Appname[62035:17503] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

does uiwebview support .msg file format ..if not how should we go about this .

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the UIWebView documentation, there's a link called "Using UIWebView to display select document types".  I don't see the ones you mention in the list.  The only options that come to mind are: create your own viewer for the unsupported ones or convert them to a different format for loading.

Comment: create your own viewer means ?? can you be more specific ..and also convert them to diffrnt format for loading means ..v should change format of the doc in backend or on the front end we can convert .msg files to some other format and then display it ??